# How to search for all names with an apostrophe by using the INSTR function in ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle

I cannot figure out how to do this. I have looked through my book on oracle SQL and it has nothing of sort about this function. I am not sure if my instructor did not mean to ask this question or if there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`INSTR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm)

> The INSTR functions search string for substring. The function returns
>   an integer indicating the position of the character in string that is
>   the first character of this occurrence.
>
> Note: If substring is not found in string, then the INSTR function will return 0.

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE INSTR(name, '''') > 0;
```

**[SQLFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5ed8ff/1/0)**

Comment: Thank you so much, I have no clue why this is not in my book.

Answer (score 1):

You can also perform

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE INSTR(name, q'!'!') > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean single quote. You can do like

```
select column_name 
from table1
where INSTR(your_column, '''') > 0;
```